# Need lazy evaluation for a function returning large data

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

Really missing Haskell right now.

I have this code:

```
for i in someFunc(arg0...argN):
    //some logic
```

The problem is that the return value of `someFunc` is massive, I'm running out of memory.

I thought I could wrap it up in a generator, but this isn't helping because I don't control `someFunc`, aka doing:

```
def gen_someFunc(someFunc):
    for i in someFunc(arg0...argN):
        yield i
```

doesn't help since `someFunc` is still evaluated immediately. How can I lazily evaluate `someFunc`?

Comment: To clarify, the problem is that `someFunc` returns a materialized dataset that is too large?

Comment: There's no general fix to this problem. You'll need to change `someFunc`, replace it, or call it in a different way.

Comment: @SeanVieira I wish I could, its blocked for me.

Comment: @larsmans: What do you mean by "call it in a different way"? I agree with the rest of your comment.

Comment: Sorry to hear that - I'm just curious - how would you deal with this problem in Haskell (Doesn't Haskell let you force the materialization of a list?)

Comment: @SeanVieira Haskell is lazy by default.

Comment: I do not get it. At some point you have to invoke the function and take the return value. You can defer the time, but you can not get only part of the return value. So what do you want to gain?

Comment: @Edgar: Haskell won't save you either. If a function decides to return `ByteString` instead of `Lazy.ByteString`, you're just as lost. You can't change the behaviour of existing code. Laziness comes at a huge cost sometimes.

Comment: @mvw I want to get only one element out of the return value at a time @ Niklas B. In this case it would have, I'm not getting a byteString back, lets just say I'm getting a massive list back.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: The point Niklas is making is that the "fault" here doesn't lie with Python (or any arbitrary non-Haskell language); it lies with whoever wrote the nonlazy function.

Comment: Sounds like you need a bigger iron.

Comment: @Edgar: A list in Haskell is equivalent to a generator in Python. So let's just say the function would return a "massive" generator, you wouldn't have the problem you have in Python either. Nobody would return "a massive list" unevaluated from a Haskell function, that's a pretty sure way to get a stack overflow (due to unevaluated thunks building up on the stack)

Comment: @JohnY Perhaps the function can be called with smaller input chunks, and those can be combined in a smarter way than the function itself does. This is how to deal with NumPy, which tends to hog memory in order to increase throughput.

Answer (score 2):

In Python (or Haskell, which this isn't), you can't lazily queue up a function that returns a fully materialized object. Lazy can happen after you use the function, but if the data is dumped on you all at once, there's nothing you can do about it.

Perhaps there are arguments for calling the function that you don't yet know about that will let you lazily evaluate it, but we don't know that from the information given here.

If you could hold  the initial call on the data in memory, the Pythonic way to call it, as a generator, would be

```
gen_some_func = iter(someFunc(arg0...argN))
```

not write this function and then call it later.

```
def gen_someFunc(someFunc):
    for i in someFunc(arg0...argN):
        yield i
```